# How to turn on/off MySQL strict mode in localhost (xampp)?

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost, mariadb, mariasql

I want to know how to check whether MySQL strict mode is on or off in localhost(xampp).

If on then for what modes and how to off.

If off then how to on.

I already followed http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-full and https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sql_mode/ and other related sites too. But I didn't get an exact answer for my question.

Comment: if you want to check strict mode then use: SELECT @@sql_mode

Comment: this query return your sql_mode and returns blank if it off

Comment: check this like [https://shopplugin.net/kb/mysql-strict-mode-issues/] to turn it on or off.

Comment: @Milan Soni: Tx for your response. The link u shared gives 'Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!'

Comment: sorry it was giving you "]" at last in url that's why. Please remove last character and check again.

Comment: @Milan Soni: Thanks for your timely response.But I have a concern that if we enable in the corresponding file and disable through sql query in the run time, then it obeys what it has done through run time. Hence I think changing the setting through sql should be followed. Again it also works for all the server. We don't need to worry about the file name and location for different server type. What do you say?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

->**STRICT_TRANS_TABLES** is responsible for setting MySQL strict mode.

->**To check** whether strict mode is enabled or not run the below sql:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

If one of the value is **STRICT_TRANS_TABLES**, then strict mode is enabled, else not.
In my case it gave

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------+ 
|Variable_name |Value                                     |
+--------------+------------------------------------------+
|sql_mode      |STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION|
+--------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Hence strict mode is **enabled** in my case as one of the value is **STRICT_TRANS_TABLES**.

->**To disable** strict mode run the below sql:

```
set global sql_mode='';
```

[or any mode except STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. Ex: set global sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';]

->To again **enable** strict mode run the below sql:

```
set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
```

Comment: If you restart mysql server then settings change back again, is there a way to change this permanently

Comment: You can do it in the server config file. Example how this would look like:

[mysqld]
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"

File location varies depending on your operating system, more on where to find it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Comment: My command `set global sql_mode=''` does not work (my version is 5.7), but `set sql_mode=''` does. Any explanation ?

Comment: @thelonglqd you may not have permissions?

Comment: To disable some mode - `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

Comment: downvote, because it's a temporary solution

Answer (score 71):

To Change it **permanently** in ubuntu do the following

in the ubuntu command line

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Then add the following

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=
```

Comment: On 16.04 in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Comment: `printf "[mysqld]\nsql_mode=\n" | sudo tee /etc/mysql/conf.d/sql_mode.cnf`

Answer (score 20):

First, check whether the strict mode is enabled or not in mysql using:

```
     SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

If you want to disable it:

```
     SET sql_mode = '';
```

or any other mode can be set except the following.
To enable strict mode:

```
     SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
```

You can check the result from the first mysql query.

Comment: Can you add it to a specific database or globally?

Comment: only for temporary use, after restart xampp it is reset to default

Answer (score 9):

Check the value with

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

then clear the @@global.sql_mode by using this command:

```
SET @@GLOBAL.sql_mode=''
```

Comment: You don't remove `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` but you clear sql_mode completely. That's a serious difference.

Answer (score 5):

To change it permanently in Windows (10), edit the `my.ini` file. To find the my.ini file, look at the path in the Windows server. E.g. for my MySQL 5.7 instance, the service is `MYSQL57`, and in this service's properties the Path to executable is:

> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MySQL57

I.e. edit the `my.ini` file in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\`. Note that `C:\ProgramData\` is a hidden folder in Windows (10). My file has the following lines of interest:

```
# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Remove `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,` from this sql-mode line, save the file and restart the MYSQL57 service. Verify the result by executing `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';` in a (new) MySQL Command Line Client window.

(I found the other answers and documents on the web useful, but none of them seem to tell you where to find the my.ini file in Windows.)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I need to add:

```
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"
```

under `[mysqld]` in the file `my.ini` located in `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know how to check whether MySQL strict mode is on or off in
> localhost(xampp).

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

If result has "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", then it's ON. Otherwise, it's OFF.

> If on then for what modes and how to off.

> If off then how to on.

For Windows,

1. Go to `C:\Program Files\MariaDB XX.X\data`
2. Open the `my.ini` file.
3. *On the line with "sql_mode", modify the value to turn strict mode ON/OFF.
4. Save the file
5. **Restart the MySQL service
6. Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'` again to see if it worked;

*3.a. To turn it ON, add `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` on that line like this: `sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`. *If there are other values already, add a comma after this then join with the rest of the value.

*3.b. To turn it OFF, simply remove `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` from value. *Remove the additional comma too if there is one.

**6. To restart the MySQL service on your computer,

1. Open the Run command window (press WINDOWS + R button).
2. Type `services.msc`
3. Click `OK`
4. Right click on the Name `MySQL`
5. Click `Restart`

Comment: Nicely written! And practical too.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the local and global value of it with:

```
SELECT @@SQL_MODE, @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE;
```

Answer (score 2):

on server console:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"
```

Answer (score 1):

on Debian 10
I start mysql from `./opt/lampp/xampp start`

I do `strace ./opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld` and see that my.cnf is there:

```
stat("/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5050, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

hence, I add sql_mode config to `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf` instead of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu :

- Once you are connected to your VPS via SSH,  please try connecting to your mysql with "root"

> user: mysql -u root -p

- Enter "root" user password and you will be in the mysql environment (mysql>), then simply check what is sql_mode, with the following command:

  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';

Basically, you will see the table as your result, if the table has a value of `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, it means that this option is enabled, so you need to remove the value from this table with the following command:

```
set global sql_mode='';
```

This will set your table's value to empty and disable this setting. Like this:

```
 +---------------+-------+
 | Variable_name | Value |
 +---------------+-------+
 | sql_mode      |       |
 +---------------+-------+
```

Please make sure to perform these commands within the MySQL environment and not simply via SSH. I think this moment was missed in the article provided below and the author assumes that the reader understands it intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

Today I was trying to set the `sql_mode=TRADITIONAL` permanently but all efforts were in vain not because there are wrong answers but due to the way xampp configured the `mysqld` startup script. Let me explain in detail.

Of course you all try our best before coming to SO, so do I. I followed the comments in `A:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` (given below):

```
# You can copy this file to
# A:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is A:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
```

So I tried `A:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf`, `A:/xampp/mysql/data/my.cnf` but it wasn't even reading those files. Hours wasted in creating `.cnf` files in above locations. Worst part was it wasn't even working if I edit those `my.ini` files (i.e `A:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini` and `A:/xampp/mysql/data/my.ini`)

Then I checked all the folders to know how that control panel works and found thta xampp uses the `mysql_start.bat` script to start the msql deamon. Here is the bat file contents:

```
@echo off
cd /D %~dp0
echo Diese Eingabeforderung nicht waehrend des Running beenden
echo Please dont close Window while MySQL is running
echo MySQL is trying to start
echo Please wait  ...
echo MySQL is starting with mysql\bin\my.ini (console)

mysql\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone

if errorlevel 1 goto error
goto finish

:error
echo.
echo MySQL konnte nicht gestartet werden
echo MySQL could not be started
pause

:finish
```

Here we can clearly see that it is explicitly using the argument `--defaults-file` to tell MySQL daemon from where to read the files. Now I hope you have plenty of ideas to fix this.

*Note: I've already added `A:/xampp/mysql/bin` to my `PATH`.*

Now we have several options as I've mentioned below:

1. Add the exact path to the `--defaults-file` (i.e. `--defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.cnf`)
2. You can just ommit the flag and let mysqld read from default locations (can see those using `mysql --help`) Now you've 2 options:

   - either edit those default `my.ini` files or
   - follow the comments to create `my.cnf` files according to your installation
     directory.

I just deleted that `--defaults-file` flag and let it run with MySQL's default configuration instead of xampp's. By the was I also have to change `A:\xampp\mysql\data\my.ini` from this:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=C:/xampp/mysql/data
[client]
```

to

```
[mysqld]
datadir=A:\xampp\mysql\data
[client]
```

to update the data directory. After that I just created a `my.conf` file in `A:\xampp\mysql\data` (data dir). with `sql_mode` option in it. It also worked with `my.cnf` in the `A:\xampp\mysql\bin`.

I have attached some screenshots for better understanding:

Updated data dir in `A:\xampp\mysql\data\my.ini`:

[image]

(option 1) Add `my.cnf` in `A:\xampp\mysql\data`:

[image]

(option 2) Add `my.cnf` in `A:\xampp\mysql\bin`:

[image]

You may found another solution too. Hope you are able to fix whatever issue you have regarding those config files.