# Disabling MySQL Strict Mode only for one query Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to disable MySQL strict mode only for one query inside a controller not for whole laravel application,

I know the risks of disabling MySQL strict mode so I don't want to disable it for my whole application from config/database.php,

I am facing problem with only one query in my whole application, so I want to disable it inside my controller before running that query only for one time!

Please help me is there any way for given situation.

Comment: for which query you need??

Comment: it is given error in a group by query, i m using laravel eloquent,
App\DefaultMilestone::where('d_dept', $user_dept)->select('d_nature')->groupby('d_nature')->get(); when i remove the select, then it will give error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881773/how-to-turn-on-off-mysql-strict-mode-in-localhost-xampp

Comment: i need to select * or select id of the row at least with group by. the table already contain data and i can't change the structure of table, when i disable the strict mode from config/database it will not give any error

Comment: but how to do it in laravel

Answer (score 17):

## Changing the strict mode in runtime

```
config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', false);
\DB::reconnect(); //important as the existing connection if any would be in strict mode
Model::select()->get(); // your query called in non strict mode

//now changing back the strict ON
config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', true);
\DB::reconnect();
```

Comment: Although it works,  disconnecting will break any transaction involved. Works only if your query is not part of a transaction. USE WITH CAUTION.

Comment: Excellent, save my code after 5hours find the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use this for MySQL ≤5.7 (taken from [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php#L177)):

```php
DB::statement("set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'");
// your query
DB::statement("set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'");
```

Comment: It works for me. What query are you executing? Why does it conflict with the strict mode?

Comment: App\DefaultMilestone::where('d_dept', $user_dept)->select('d_nature')->groupby('d_nature')->get();

Comment: Why doesn't this query work in strict mode? What's the error?

Comment: This is working, when i want to select * and group by b_nature then it will give error in strict mode!

Comment: You have to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, I updated my answer.

Comment: maybe it works for you but not working for me, it doesn't mean that your answer is wrong, thanks for help dear!

Answer (score 3):

One thing tha you can do is to change this value at run time

```
public function doQueryWithoutStrictMode{
    config('database.connections.mysql.strict', false);
    DB::select('The query you want to make, and that should work!');

    And then, if you later want to do another query in strict mode withing the same 
    method you can enable it like this.

    config('database.connections.mysql.strict', true);

    DB::select('your other query with strict mode');

}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but i have tried and it is not working, have you tried it?

Comment: i have tried this too config(['database.connections.mysql.strict' => false]);

Answer (score 2):

In config/database.php, do as like:

'connections' => [

```
    'mysql' => [

        // Behave like MySQL 5.6

        'strict' => false,

        // Behave like MySQL 5.7
        'strict' => true,
    ]
```

]

Comment: it will change the strict mode for whole application, and it will be a risk