# how to use "groupBy" with relationship Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to do a grouping by date. The problem that are two tables "kanban" and "apontamentos".

something like: Kanban::with('apontamentos')->get()->groupBy('dataApontamento');
**property error**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoaEl.jpg)

*I've tried everything, use "groupBy" in the model. Need to know how to group in the controller and do the "foreach"*

closest I ever got was that way:

```
$days = Kanban::with('apontamentos')->get()->groupBy(function ($val) {
      return $val->dataApontamento;
  });
  // dd($days);

  foreach ($days as $day => $appointments) {
    echo '<h2>'.$day.'</h2><ul>';
    foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {
        echo '<li>'.$appointment->atividade.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul><br>';
  }
```

clearer example:

Kanban

**Title: waiting for service**

Apontamentos

**date 05/05**

Project1

Project2

Project3

**date 06/05**

Project1

Project2

Project6

Project7

Kanban

**Title: pending**

apontamentos

**date: 08/05**

Project9

Project8

Project4

Kanban

Title: Kanban

**Title: waiting for service**

apontamentos

**date: 09/05**

Project1

Project1

Project1

Project1

**10/05**

Project1

Project1

Project1

Project1

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
Kanban::with(['apontamentos' => function($query){
    $query->groupBy('dataApontamento');
}])->get();
```

Comment: thanks @Alex for responding, gave this error.

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'company.apontamentos.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `apontamentos` where `apontamentos`.`kanban_id` in (7, 10, 11, 12) group by `dataApontamento`)

Comment: you have to put company.apontamentos.id in the group by or you have to tell laravel to use strict mode false for the database you have to go to config/database and in the mysql put this 'strict' => false

Comment: same mistake...
 `'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,`

Comment: check in you db if your mysql have the stict mode to fale 
 with  SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode  and you can change it by SET @@GLOBAL.sql_mode=''"

Comment: how to explain it better? I use xampp

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881773/how-to-turn-on-off-mysql-strict-mode-in-localhost-xampp