# MySQL 5.7 file for strict mode - linux - no file

Tags: mysql, bash

On my BlueHost VPS I'm trying to turn `strict mode` off permanently, via config file. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.ma-no.org/en/networking/databases/how-to-disable-strict-sql-mode-in-mysql-5-7-and-ubuntu-16-04), but it didn't work.

1. `/etc/mysql/conf.d/disable_strict_mode.cnf` didn't exist, so I tried to create it.
2. I found that `/etc/` existed, but nothing after that (in the path shown).
3. I created `/etc/mysql`, then `conf.d` after that, and finally I created the file `disable_strict_mode.cnf`, added the 2 lines, saved, restarted mysql. No joy.

So I'm wondering if on BlueHost (CentOS), maybe the mysql configuration file is elsewhere?

I also tried looking at `/etc/my.cnf`, which has lots of settings, but no `[mysqld]` section, and no `sql_mode` setting.

Question: Which file should I be editing, and if `my.cnf`, should I add a [mysqld] section (it doesn't exist)? Or should I be creating `disable_strict_mode.cnf` in some other directory?

Note: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` doesn't exist on my server. Is it elsewhere? Should I be editing that file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn on/off MySQL strict mode in localhost (xampp)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881773/how-to-turn-on-off-mysql-strict-mode-in-localhost-xampp)

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you nbk. Editing `/etc/my.cnf` solved it.