# SQL error 1364 code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu

Whenever i try to start unencrypted.js

```
pm2 start unencrypted.js && pm2 logs
```

Ill get this error message

```
0|unencryp |     at Connection.query (/var/www/html/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
0|unencryp |     at createRaffle (/var/www/html/socket/unencrypted.js:3335:10)
0|unencryp |     at checkCurrentRaffles (/var/www/html/socket/unencrypted.js:3724:13)
0|unencryp |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/www/html/socket/unencrypted.js:3647:26)
0|unencryp |     at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
0|unencryp |     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
0|unencryp |     at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
0|unencryp |     at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
0|unencryp |   code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
0|unencryp |   errno: 1364,
0|unencryp |   sqlMessage: 'Field \'winner_steamid\' doesn\'t have a default value',
0|unencryp |   sqlState: 'HY000',
0|unencryp |   index: 0,
0|unencryp |   sql:
0|unencryp |    'INSERT INTO raffles SET tipul = 0, item_id = \'0\' , item_name = \'1500 Coins\', item_image = \'http://192.168.1.12/vendor/img/icon-coins.png\', item_price = 1500, slots = 2\n    , price_per_ticket = 810, hash = \'d5569dca5a7f52439ad05c3e236be56002d6134b015580608960aebb75425f7c\', secrets = \'BP2b0lOMmbafXyDl-8cMoxLt9ZSj6yyv8\', secret_winner = \'BP2b0lOMmbafXyDl\'\n    , secret_number = 0, time = 1612371932' }
```

I tried setting 0 as a default value for `winner_steamid` but it didnt work maybe you guys can help me

Comment: I know it's too late to add on this, but stumbled on this when looking for answer for a similar problem myself which seems to have been sorted by disabling strict mode. What happens/ed if you try/ied by disabling the strict mode in mysql? 
`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';`  to see what's the current value and set it to empty by `SET sql_mode = '';`

- reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881773/how-to-turn-on-off-mysql-strict-mode-in-localhost-xampp#40889485